# Find all slots in a given range

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

How to find all the date slots in a range..

From Date `01- Jan -2014 00:00:00 A.M`

To Date `15-Oct-2014 00:00:00 P.M`

Event Start Date `03-Jan-2014 10:00 A.M` occurs every 3 days once mean 03, 06, 09, etc

I need to calculate like below **using c#**

03-Jan-2014

06-Jan-2014

09-Jan-2014

12-Jan-2014

etc,etc

How this calculations can be done in c#? tried in DB and failed, check [Display next event date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286332/display-next-event-date)

Comment: Did you try with [`AddDays()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method first?

Comment: @SonerGönül, AddDays i can add. But how can i add it in a loop till the end?

Comment: @SonerGönül, sometime they asking me to do it every tuesday :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use [`DateTime.AddDays()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2014, 10, 15);
DateTime start = new DateTime(2014, 1, 3);

while (start < dt2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(start.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
    start = start.AddDays(3);
}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/lAzNe7)</kbd>.

If you want to show 1`5-Oct-2014` also as a result, just change your `start < dt2` condition to `start <= dt2`

Output will be;

```
03-Jan-2014
06-Jan-2014
09-Jan-2014
12-Jan-2014
15-Jan-2014
18-Jan-2014
21-Jan-2014
24-Jan-2014
27-Jan-2014
30-Jan-2014
02-Feb-2014
05-Feb-2014
08-Feb-2014
11-Feb-2014
14-Feb-2014
17-Feb-2014
20-Feb-2014
23-Feb-2014
26-Feb-2014
01-Mar-2014
04-Mar-2014
07-Mar-2014
10-Mar-2014
13-Mar-2014
16-Mar-2014
19-Mar-2014
22-Mar-2014
25-Mar-2014
28-Mar-2014
31-Mar-2014
03-Apr-2014
06-Apr-2014
09-Apr-2014
12-Apr-2014
15-Apr-2014
18-Apr-2014
21-Apr-2014
24-Apr-2014
27-Apr-2014
30-Apr-2014
03-May-2014
06-May-2014
09-May-2014
12-May-2014
15-May-2014
18-May-2014
21-May-2014
24-May-2014
27-May-2014
30-May-2014
02-Jun-2014
05-Jun-2014
08-Jun-2014
11-Jun-2014
14-Jun-2014
17-Jun-2014
20-Jun-2014
23-Jun-2014
26-Jun-2014
29-Jun-2014
02-Jul-2014
05-Jul-2014
08-Jul-2014
11-Jul-2014
14-Jul-2014
17-Jul-2014
20-Jul-2014
23-Jul-2014
26-Jul-2014
29-Jul-2014
01-Aug-2014
04-Aug-2014
07-Aug-2014
10-Aug-2014
13-Aug-2014
16-Aug-2014
19-Aug-2014
22-Aug-2014
25-Aug-2014
28-Aug-2014
31-Aug-2014
03-Sep-2014
06-Sep-2014
09-Sep-2014
12-Sep-2014
15-Sep-2014
18-Sep-2014
21-Sep-2014
24-Sep-2014
27-Sep-2014
30-Sep-2014
03-Oct-2014
06-Oct-2014
09-Oct-2014
12-Oct-2014
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use LINQ then you can do:

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(2014, 10, 15);

int difference = 3;
List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>(new[] { dtStart });
result.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, (dtEnd - dtStart).Days / difference)
                           .Select(r => dtStart = dtStart.AddDays(difference)));
```

Comment: Is it possible from the given date, check the next monday date?

Comment: @Billa, yes it is possible but it would require a different code, and it is out of context with this question.