# Get records based on Current Date and Configured Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, datediff

I am working on automating the SMS sending part in my web application.

[**SQL Fiddle Link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a18de/2)

**DurationType** table stores whether the sms should be sent out an interval of Hours, Days, Weeks, Months. Referred in SMSConfiguration

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationType](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[DurationType] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

**Bookings** table Contains the original Bookings data. For this booking I need to send the SMS based on configuration.

[image]

**SMS Configuration**. Which defines the configuration for sending automatic SMS. It can be send before/after. Before=0, After=1. `DurationType can be Hours=1, Days=2, Weeks=3, Months=4`

[image]

Now I need to find out the list of bookings that needs SMS to be sent out at the current time based on the SMS Configuration Set.

**Tried SQL using UNION**

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 11:15:00'


-- 'SMS CONFIGURED FOR HOURS BASIS'

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, 
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,@currentTime As CurrentTime,  SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
WHERE   (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=1 AND BeforeAfter=0)
        OR
        (DATEDIFF(HOUR, B.StartTime, @currentTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=1 AND BeforeAfter=1)


--'SMS CONFIGURED FOR DAYS BASIS'

UNION

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, 
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,@currentTime As CurrentTime,  SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=2 AND BeforeAfter=0)
        OR
      (DATEDIFF(DAY, B.StartTime, @currentTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=2 AND BeforeAfter=1)
--'SMS CONFIGURED FOR WEEKS BASIS'

UNION

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, 
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime, @currentTime As CurrentTime, SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime)/7 = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=3 AND BeforeAfter=0)
        OR
      (DATEDIFF(DAY, B.StartTime, @currentTime)/7 = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=3 AND BeforeAfter=1)
--'SMS CONFIGURED FOR MONTHS BASIS'

UNION

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, 
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime, @currentTime As CurrentTime, SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
WHERE   (dbo.FullMonthsSeparation(@currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=4 AND BeforeAfter=0)
         OR
        (dbo.FullMonthsSeparation(B.StartTime, @currentTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=4 AND BeforeAfter=1)
```

**Result**

[image]

**Problem:**

The SQL procedure will be running every 15 mins. Current query keep returning  days/weeks/months records even for the current time '2014-07-12 11:30:00', '2014-07-12 11:45:00', etc

> I want a single query that takes care of all Hours/Days/Weeks/Months
>   calculation and I should be get records only one time when they meet
>   the correct time. Otherwise I will be sending sms again and again
>   every 15 mins for day/week/months records matched.

It should consider the following scenarios.

1. Hour, If booking is 10:15 A.M same day 9:15 A.M if it is before 1 hour configured
2. Day(24 Hour difference), If booking is 10:15 A.M 3rd day morning 10:15 A.M if it is configured after 3 days in SMSConfiguration
3. Match Week. If booking is 10:15 A.M today(Wednesday) morning then after 14 days morning 10:15 A.M if it is configured after 2 weeks.
4. Month also same logic like above.

Comment: In the given fiddle link, I removed the termination character (`;`) , changed the wrong alias name (**S** to **SMS**) and swap the dates in DATEDIFF. It worked well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the simplified version [**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24708/65) , removed Union and used OR conditions

**LIST FOR HOURS - RUN Every 15 mins**

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 11:15:00'



SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, C.Id, C.Name,
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,@currentTime As CurrentTime,  SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
        LEFT JOIN Category C ON C.Id=B.CategoryId
WHERE   
        (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration*60 AND SMS.DurationType=1 AND BeforeAfter=0)
        OR
        (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, B.StartTime, @currentTime) = SMS.Duration*60 AND SMS.DurationType=1 AND BeforeAfter=1)

Order BY B.Id

GO
```

**LIST FOR DAYS/WEEKS/MONTHS - RUN Every Day Morning Once**

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 08:00:00'

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, C.Id, C.Name,
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,@currentTime As CurrentTime,  SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
        LEFT JOIN Category C ON C.Id=B.CategoryId
WHERE   
    (((DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=2)
    OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration*7 AND SMS.DurationType=3)
    OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration*30 AND SMS.DurationType=4))
     AND BeforeAfter=0)

    OR
    (((DATEDIFF(DAY, B.StartTime, @currentTime) = SMS.Duration AND SMS.DurationType=2)
    OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration*7 AND SMS.DurationType=3)
    OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration*30 AND SMS.DurationType=4))
     AND BeforeAfter=1)

Order BY B.Id
```

Comment: The idea looks good. But you have used 30 days for calculating month. What about month with 28/31 days?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to pick some columns to return.

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 09:15:00'; 

SELECT [col1], [col2], [etcetera]
FROM

Bookings B
INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId=B.CategoryId
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour,B.StartTime,@currentTime)=1
```

Comment: Sorry.. Updated. My actual question is about retreiving data based on the configuration set. Not to hard code hour and value 1

Comment: ah, makes more sense that way to ;) can you specify the results you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Just `swap the dates in DATEDIFF` function

> Change **DATEDIFF(hour, B.StartTime, @currentTime)** to **DATEDIFF(hour, @currentTime, B.StartTime)** - *for HOUR only*

Because yours one return the value in **Negative** (-1).

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 09:15:00'

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, @currentTime AS CurrentTime,
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,  SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
WHERE   (SMS.CategoryId IS NOT NULL AND 
         DATEDIFF(HOUR, @currentTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration) OR 
        (SMS.CategoryId IS NULL AND 
         (DATEDIFF(DAY, B.StartTime, @currentTime) = SMS.Duration OR 
          DATEDIFF(MONTH, B.StartTime, @currentTime) = SMS.Duration))
```

Comment: Its not working. I tried copy pasted your code in fiddle and got error `Must declare the scalar variable "@currentTime"`

Comment: It gives only one record. See my expected result in my question. I want other records based on Days/Weeks/Months configured :(

Comment: Updated... please check now

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66e97/3 . You are 50% correct. But when i add one more entry in SMS Configuration & Booking table it shows more records. `Rows 2, 4, 5, 8 should not be displayed in a result, as they are not meeting the criteria`

Comment: Thanks. But still `Row #2 ->It should not be shown as it has more than one hour(1 day)`and `Row 5 -> Should not shown now. But it will be shown when the @currentTime is 2014-07-12 10:15:00`. Hope you got my requirement. The SQL procedure will be run every 15 mins and find the records matching to send the SMS

Comment: Updated a question with more details and with bounty too

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime
set @currentTime= '2014-07-12 09:15:00'



SELECT B.CategoryId FROM
Bookings B
INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId=B.CategoryId
WHERE DATEDIFF(hh,B.StartTime,@currentTime)=1
```

There were two problems in your sql fiddle

1) you didn't set the value of `currentTime`

2) there were columns in your select statement

**Note:** I took `B.CategoryId` as one of the column to fetch records, you can change it as per your requirement

Comment: Updated my question with expected result. Check it. Its not only based on Hour, its based on months/days configured

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested CASE expressions for achieve your results in single query. please try this,

```
    DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 11:15:00'





    SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId,
    SMS.Duration,
    B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,
    @currentTime As CurrentTime,  
    SMS.SMSText
    FROM Bookings B INNER JOIN
    SMSConfiguration SMS 
    ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId 
    OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL


    WHERE 
       SMS.Duration = 
       CASE 
       WHEN SMS.DurationType = 1 THEN  --'SMS CONFIGURED FOR HOURS BASIS'


           CASE WHEN BeforeAfter = 0 THEN 
                DATEDIFF(HOUR, @currentTime, B.StartTime)       
           ELSE 
                DATEDIFF(HOUR, B.StartTime, @currentTime)
           END 

       WHEN SMS.DurationType = 2 THEN  --'SMS CONFIGURED FOR DAY BASIS'


           CASE WHEN BeforeAfter = 0 THEN 
              DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime)         
          ELSE 
              DATEDIFF(DAY, B.StartTime, @currentTime)
          END 

     WHEN SMS.DurationType = 3 THEN  --'SMS CONFIGURED FOR WEEK BASIS'


          CASE WHEN BeforeAfter = 0 THEN 
              DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentTime, B.StartTime)/7        
          ELSE 
              DATEDIFF(DAY, B.StartTime, @currentTime)/7 
          END 

      ELSE 
          CASE WHEN BeforeAfter = 0 THEN -- 'SMS CONFIGURED FOR MONTH BASIS'
              dbo.FullMonthsSeparation(@currentTime, B.StartTime)        
          ELSE 
              dbo.FullMonthsSeparation(B.StartTime, @currentTime) 
          END    

      END 

    ORDER BY BOOKINGID;
```

you can automate in two schedules one for getting booking details of Hourly sms and other one for Daily/Weekly/Monthly booking details.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 09:15:00'

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, 
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,  
        @currentTime CURRENT_DT,
        SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
WHERE  (    SMS.DurationType = 1 
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(HOUR, (2*SMS.BeforeAfter-1)*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
     OR 
       (    SMS.DurationType = 2
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(DAY, (2*SMS.BeforeAfter-1)*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
     OR
       (    SMS.DurationType = 3
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(WEEK, (2*SMS.BeforeAfter-1)*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
     OR
       (    SMS.DurationType = 4
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(MONTH, (2*SMS.BeforeAfter-1)*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
```

The 2*SMS.BeforeAfter-1  converts Before(0) to -1 and After(1) to 1. Thus, adding or subtracting time from the BookingStartTime

**[Edit]**

The above solution should work with your data model as is. Below I propose simplifying the solution by changing your data model.

### Option 1: Change Before and After meta data

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e9e9/1

Instead of `Before = 0` and `After = 1`, use `Before = -1` and `After = 1`. Then these can be used to change the direction of any date offset

For example:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SMSConfiguration]
           ([CategoryId],[SMSText],[BeforeAfter],[Duration],[DurationType],[IsActive])
     VALUES
           (1,'Before 1 hour',-1,1,1,1)-- 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SMSConfiguration]
           ([CategoryId],[SMSText],[BeforeAfter],[Duration],[DurationType],[IsActive])
     VALUES
           (NULL,'After 1 hour (no category id))',1,1,1,1)
```

Updated query:

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 09:15:00'

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, 
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,  
        @currentTime CURRENT_DT,
        SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
WHERE  (    SMS.DurationType = 1 
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(HOUR, SMS.BeforeAfter*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
     OR 
       (    SMS.DurationType = 2
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(DAY, SMS.BeforeAfter*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
     OR
       (    SMS.DurationType = 3
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(WEEK, SMS.BeforeAfter*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
     OR
       (    SMS.DurationType = 4
        AND @currentTime = DATEADD(MONTH, SMS.BeforeAfter*SMS.Duration, B.StartTime))
```

### Option 2: Allow 30-days = 1 month

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/808cd/1

On top of the Before/After change, if a 30 day period is close enough to represent a month, then all duration types could be converted to hours. The question is how particular your customers will be in regard to precision. If you are off by a day or two on a "3 month before" rule, I don't think you will have many complaints.

So your DurationType table could look like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationType](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[DurationType] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
[HourConversion] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DurationType]([Id],[DurationType],[HourConversion])
       VALUES(1,'Hours',1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DurationType]([Id],[DurationType],[HourConversion])
       VALUES(2,'Days',24)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DurationType]([Id],[DurationType],[HourConversion])
       VALUES(3,'Weeks',24*7)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DurationType]([Id],[DurationType],[HourConversion])
       VALUES(4,'Months',24*30)
```

With these changes, the query could be modified to:

```
DECLARE @currentTime smalldatetime = '2014-07-12 09:15:00'

SELECT  B.Id AS BookingId, 
        B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime,  
        @currentTime CURRENT_DT,
        SMS.SMSText
FROM    Bookings B 
INNER JOIN
        SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
INNER JOIN
        DurationType DT ON DT.Id = SMS.DurationType
WHERE  @currentTime = DATEADD(HOUR, SMS.BeforeAfter*SMS.Duration*DT.HourConversion, B.StartTime)
```

Comment: For one booking i may able to send multiple sms. Like one hour before, after 2 hour, after 1 month, after 3 months, etc. Do you think this logic will work out?

Comment: I think my latest edit should work, but you need more data to test it thoroughly. May be better if you stored Before as -1 and After as 1. then you wouldn't have to do the extra math.

Comment: Something else to consider. Can 30 days be considered 1 month? If so, then store the duration in hours for all of the duration types 1 hour = 1, 1 day = 24, 1 week = 24*7, 1 month = 24*7*30. Then you don't need to check the DurationType; just DATEADD(HOUR) in all cases

Comment: What is 2*SMS.BeforeAfter? February got only 28 and some months have 31 days. Thats why i have a UD function for that

Comment: I explained 2*SMS.BeforeAfter-1 at the bottom of my answer. Basically, you need to take the booking time and add or subtract time. So we need -1*duration for Before and 1*duration for After. You have Before=0 and After=1. What you really need is Before=-1 and After=1. I commented this on an earlier post.

Comment: @Billa The answer works for all months. I was asking about the business rules to see if there was a way to simplify the answer. If 30 days is close enough, then everything can be represented as hours.

Comment: Correction on the month to hour conversion, should be `1 month = 24*30 hours` see edited answer for working solution

Comment: better yet, for performance, presuming the StartTime is indexed: do the DATEADD on the @currentTime, not the StartTime... `WHERE  B.StartTime = DATEADD(HOUR, -1*SMS.BeforeAfter*SMS.Duration*DT.HourConversion, @currentTime)`